# Expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency, No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to perform Gradle build on my application but build is getting failed due to below Exception,
Can you suggest what can be the possible reason for this?

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers'
>   parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'requestConfig':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'requestInterceptor':
>   No qualifying bean of type [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor]
>   found for dependency [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor]
>   found for dependency [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested exception is
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'requestConfig': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'requestInterceptor': No qualifying bean of
>   type [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor] found for dependency
>   [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor]: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor]
>   found for dependency [com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have performed autowiring of RequestInterceptor in RequestConfig

RequestConfig  Class:

```
package com.cspt.config;

import com.cspt.interceptor.RequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
class RequestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        // Register interceptor class and Exclude request on the registered class
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/api/users/search","/api/systemuser/search", "/api/svn/search", "/api/project/search/**");
    }
}
```

RequestInterceptor  Class :

```
package com.cspt.interceptor;

import com.cspt.orm.domain.UserAccessLogs;
import com.cspt.orm.services.UserAccessLogsService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccessLogsService userAccessLogsService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response, Object object) {
        try {
            String fullUrl;

            //returns the part of the full URL before query string separator character '?'
            StringBuilder requestURL = new StringBuilder(request.getRequestURL().toString());

            //returns the part of the full URL after query string separator character '?'
            String queryString = request.getQueryString();

            //returns URI
            String action = request.getRequestURI();

            //returns Remote Address of the User
            String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

            //returns logged in user
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String userName = auth.getName();

            if (queryString == null) {
                fullUrl = requestURL.toString();
            } else {
                fullUrl = requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();
            }

            LOG.info("Request parameters. Timestamp: {}, User: {}, Remote Address: {}, Action: {}, Full URL: {} ", LocalDateTime.now(), userName, remoteAddress, action, fullUrl);

            //Save records
            UserAccessLogs userAccessLogs = new UserAccessLogs(LocalDateTime.now(), userName, remoteAddress, action, fullUrl);
            userAccessLogsService.save(userAccessLogs);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while adding access logs for user ", e);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your componentScan path ?

Comment: Thank you very much, entry of my new package was missing in Test package, where componentScan was defined.

Comment: This is working for me now.

Comment: You might want to add an answer with the cause/solution, and accept it.